# How to compile the spring sourcecode

Tags: java, spring, cglib

When I compiled the Spring sourcecode, I got following problem.

I can't get the file spring-cglib-repack-3.1.jar. what shall do? help me please.
I used the Gradle to compile the source code.

Comment: Why do you want to compile Spring? What's wrong with the official binaries?

Comment: Are you using IDE or are you using command line to develop?

Comment: Check if you have added jars or in case of maven check repository

Comment: @Thilo I just want to learn the sourcecode of Spring...

Comment: @Aeseir I use the eclipse and I use the command line gradle cleanidea eclipse.

Comment: @Veke I can't get the jar file named spring-cglib-repack-3.1.jar.I can search the web to get the file named spring-cglib-repack-3.0.jar.but I can get the the former

Comment: do you want to download jar? or you have it and your applocation is unable to find it? Go throught tutorial link provided by me It will help you for sure

Comment: doesn't the Gradle build create that jar file? It is libraries that Spring repackages for internal use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you are a newbie for **SPRING**

please visit following tutorial
Its a best one for a beginner 
[Spring + Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/)

Even you will find dozens of examples each example explains topic step by step.

I hope this helps you.